# Post-shuttle, "Have any animals that have been studied onboard the ISS come back alive?"

Tags: iss, research, animals

The nicely and carefully written question [Have any animals that have been studied onboard the ISS come back alive?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3262/12102) has an affirmative answer that applies to the space shuttle. Now that return to Earth comes in capsule form, have animals ever returned live to the surface — *by design?*

Comment: Not counting homo sapiens animals, I assume?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have heard that at least in the early days, the astronaut ecperience may have sometimes felt like being an experimental subject, but in this case I mean the ones riding as cargo, not with seats. :)

Comment: Did you see the commentary about the zebrafish on the linked question?

Comment: @called2voyage Comments and answers are like zebras and fish - two different things. I think I still remember how hard you worked to teach me that comments could suddenly "be disappeared" at any moment without warning, so I strive to move useful information to slightly more durable answers. :)  Here or there is fine, as long as there's some link or citation. We can mark this one as a duplicate if needed.

Comment: @uhoh I agree it needs to be made into an actual answer, but I wanted to make sure that you saw the information that technically answers your question.

Comment: @called2voyage Oh I see! No I hadn't seen it, thanks for mentioning those comments - I must have skimmed over everything too quickly, thanks. There's even a tweet about a fish named after a zebra!

Comment: I'm still waiting for someone to post an answer explaining that humans are certainly animals and experimented on; kept in confined spaces, forced to run for hours, poked, prodded, sampled, measured and observed, and generally returned to Earth alive, so I've un-accepted my answer ;-)

Comment: @uhoh But haven't you ruled out that interpretation by your very first comment above, where you restricted the question to animals "riding as cargo"?

Comment: @TooTea You are right. *Rats!* (pun intended)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

A nice example would be the recent splashdown of the first SpaceX Dragon capsule to have been re-used after a previous visit to the ISS.

See for example Spaceflight Now's July 3, 2017 article [Dragon capsule returns home with animals and station equipment](https://spaceflightnow.com/2017/07/03/dragon-capsule-returns-home-with-animals-and-station-equipment/):

> Items stowed for Dragon’s return included live mice from an experiment to investigate the effectiveness of a therapeutic drug to promote bone growth, combating atrophy in astronauts in space and osteoporosis patients on Earth. The mice will be euthanized and examined after landing.

---

**below:** "The Dragon spacecraft was lifted onto a boat for a trip back to port in Southern California following Monday’s predawn splashdown. Credit: SpaceX" From [here](https://spaceflightnow.com/2017/07/03/dragon-capsule-returns-home-with-animals-and-station-equipment/).

[image]

Comment: "The mice will be euthanized" tough break after such a long journey for a mouse!

Comment: @SarahBailey I couldn't think of a good way to point out the irony, "tough break" does it very nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Other answers focused on Rodent Research, which is long running series of experiments which often have live rodents returned to Earth. One such experiment was **[Rodent Research 6.](https://www.nasa.gov/mission/station/research-explorer/investigation/?#id=7423)**

Other examples include:

**[Fruit Fly Lab 02](https://www.nasa.gov/mission/station/research-explorer/investigation/?#id=1662)**

- Live fruit flies that hatched in space were returned to Earth on [SpaceX-11](https://www.nasa.gov/ames/space-biosciences/fruit-fly-lab-02-spacex-11/).
  [image]

**[XENOGRISS](https://www.nasa.gov/mission/station/research-explorer/investigation/?#id=7924)**

- Live tadpoles were flown and returned to Earth on SpaceX-19.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Rodent research is a big science objective for NASA. NASA and JAXA send rodents via Dragon and Cygnus capsules very frequently, and they are returned to Earth via Dragon re-entry.

Here's a 40+ page review:

- [A Researcher’s Guide to: Rodent Research](https://www.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/np-2015-03-016-jsc_rodent-iss-mini-book_detail-508.pdf)

And from this NASA.gov mission page: [Rodent Research - Active Mission](https://science.nasa.gov/mission/rodent-research/) please see:

> Rodent Research-5
>
> The topic of study on this mission was bone tissue loss – a challenge for the health of astronauts, as well as for people on Earth suffering from osteoporosis. For the experiment, a group of mice was launched to the space station in June 2017. Half of them returned to Earth one month later, while the other half remained in space for a full two months. This allowed the researchers – a team based at University of California, Los Angeles – to study the effects of a potential treatment for bone loss, and how the body readapts to Earth conditions after an extended stay in microgravity.

Comment: All links go to 404

Comment: This is also what's called a link-only answer. Even if the links worked, there is no answer here, one would have to go off-site to get any real answer. Can you quote some short sections of each link that answer the question so that this becomes a stand-alone answer? Thanks!

Comment: @OrganicMarble links fixed (it seems they were given more permanent homes?)