# How much gravity could someone handle who lived his/her entire life in microgravity?

Tags: gravity, microgravity, medical

Let's say someone who was conceived and born in microgravity and spent his/her entire life on a space station in weightlessness until age 20 decides to land on a celestial body. How much surface gravity would such a celestial body have to have for the human to get accustomed to it? Such a human obviously cannot land on any of the four inner planets where he/she would probably die instantly since his/her bones would break. However the human still has some strength because he/she might have moved more massive things sometimes, for instance.

What if such a person would try to land on Lutetia in 0.003g or Ceres in 0.029g or Pluto in 0.063g? What would happen to him/her?

Comment: What are your opinion on [rat babies in space](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1464515/)? I feel like a lot of the interesting things observed in rats raised from birth in space may also apply to humans. In addition to that, we're closely observing astronaut health; watch an astronaut take their [first few steps when they land (or not)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bw5aVu_PeFg). Now imagine a baby who can't exercise existing in space for a long time. They may not develop the basic musculature to even manage to hold their heads up in 1g, 0.5g or possibly even less.

Comment: +1 though, I'm interested in how much we've studied the impact on *human* babies due to ethical concerns. There are a lot more studies on those rats, by the way. I'd look into some of those they are quite interesting :).

Comment: `-1` and I've voted to close because "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers." There are not going to be any fact-based and sourced answers about humans who are "conceived and born in microgravity and spent their entire life on a space station in weightlessness until age 20". While this is an intriguing topic, it's not suitable for this Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @uhoh Just because we aren't 100% sure doesn't mean that we shouldn't try to figure it out.

Comment: @user30007 well i guess you might want to check out someplace like Worldbuilding if its getting closed here

Comment: @Topcode  Worldbuilding depends a lot on unobtanium.   I would move this to  a medical or biomechanical group if there is such a thing.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft i know, but worldbuilding has a hard-science tag, im just saying if this gets closed its the next place to go

Comment: No, my question is not opinion-based. It has a clear answer, and whether you know the answer has nothing to do with opinion. There may be differences in gender and in how much he/she prepares for the landing on a certain celestial body. But you could have given an example or answered several possible scenarios. If you dunno it's no reason to close the question. There are years-old unanswered questions on SE.

Comment: @user30007 I don't like voting to close questions and I'm sorry to vtc this one, but the close reason is "This question is likely to be *answered with opinions rather than facts* and citations. *It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers*." Again, There are not going to be any fact-based and sourced answers about humans who are "conceived and born in microgravity and spent their entire life on a space station in weightlessness until age 20". Answers would be pure speculation and therefore no appropriate as Stack Exchange answers.

Comment: You could consider editing this question and ask *what if anything is known* about mammalian cell growth and differentiation in microgravity, or even ask if mice or other mammals have been born in space and if so how they developed. You could even ask if they were then returned to Earth and how they adjusted to gravity. But this question, as currently asked is not answerable to the degree appropriate for a Stack Exchange answer. Have a look at [Post-shuttle, “Have any animals that have been studied onboard the ISS come back alive?”](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20361/12102) for example.

Comment: @uhoh My question rather is concerning humans. But I'll ask a similar but different question on it.